# How to recompile a widget's templateUrl in Malhar AngularJS dashboard framework

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using the Malhar AngularJS Dashboard Framework located here on github: https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard , and a simple demo here: http://datatorrent.github.io/malhar-angular-dashboard/#/ .

Their system uses JQuery Sortable Widgets, which allows me to load up some charts and grids into a dashboard.

The way I load my charts and grids is by using their `templateUrl` property on the widget definition, as follows :

`{
   name: myWidgetEnum.TREELIST,
   title: 'Tree List',
   templateUrl: 'app/shared/gadget-templates/tree-list.html'
 }`

Here's a more complete sample of the Malhar Widget Definitions, which is where I define my UI "gadgets" to be rendered within the sortable widgets :

```js
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('rage')    
.factory('widgetDefinitions', ['ColumnChartDataModel', 'TreeListDataModel', 'TreeMapDataModel', 'GridDataModel', widgetDefinitions])

var myWidgetEnum = Object.freeze({        
TREELIST: 'chart_treelist',
TREEMAP: 'chart_treemap',
HEATMAP: 'chart_heatmap',
GRID: 'chart_grid'
});

/* Define the widget definitions - base properties are defined in WidgetModel factory.
*/
function widgetDefinitions(ColumnChartDataModel, TreeListDataModel, TreeMapDataModel, GridDataModel) {

var size = { width: '20%', height: 90 };
var fixedSize = { width: '50%', height: 320 };  // keep height as a number, and add 'px' in directive
var initImagePath = 'images4/256x256/';

return [
    {                
 name: myWidgetEnum.TREELIST,
 title: 'Tree List',
 templateUrl: 'app/shared/gadget-templates/tree-list.html',                
 dataModelType: TreeListDataModel,
 dataModelOptions: {},               // this property will be persisted in DashboardState factory 
 gadgetType: 'table',
 chartType: 'treelist',
 settingsModalOptions: { }                
    },    
    {
 name: myWidgetEnum.HEATMAP,
 title: 'Heat Map',
 templateUrl: 'app/shared/gadget-templates/grid.html',
 dataModelType: GridDataModel,
 dataModelOptions: {},               // this property will be persisted in DashboardState factory
 gadgetType: 'table',
 chartType: 'heatmap',
 settingsModalOptions: {} // see 'MainCtrl' controller
    }
];
}
  
})();
```

And the dashboard options in my main controller :

```js
$scope.dashboardOptions = {
    widgetButtons: false,   // 'false' makes it a dropdown of options
    widgetDefinitions: widgetDefinitions,   // see dashboard-widget-factory.js
    defaultWidgets: defaultWidgets,
    storage: $window.localStorage,
    storageId: $scope.defaultDashboardId,       // 'rage.ui' - no longer hard code the storage Id - 06/11/2015 BM:
    hideWidgetSettings: false,
    settingsModalOptions: {   
 templateUrl: 'app/shared/include/gadget-config-new/gadget-config-container.html',
 controller: 'GadgetSettingsCtrl_NEW as settings',
 backdrop: true
    },
    onSettingsClose: function (result, widget) {
 jQuery.extend(true, widget, result);
 widget.dataModelOptions = result.dataModelOptions;
    },
    onSettingsDismiss: function (reason) { 
       console.log('widget settings were dismissed. Reason: ', reason);
    }
};
```

When Malhar first loads up the widgets, it `compiles` the `templateUrl` within the JQuery sortable widget.

However, if I launch the widget settings modal and choose a different "widget" from the Widget Definitions list, I'm having an issue when I try to `recompile` the new `templateUrl`.

In other words if the first widget loaded up is the `TREELIST`, then in it's modal settings I choose a new widget called `HEATMAP`, I need to somehow force a recompile on the new html template that was loaded by Malhar.

Here on github, you can find the main directive, `malhar-angular-dashboard.js` https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard/blob/master/dist/malhar-angular-dashboard.js , and if you search down for the `'DashboardWidgetCtrl'` controller you'll find the `$scope.makeTemplateString` function as well as the `$scope.compileTemplate` function further below that.

I'm experimenting with the resolve section of the $modal instance as follows, but this seems to be more of a hack than an elegant solution:

See the `angular.element` below inside the `try...catch` section :

```js
// Set resolve and reject callbacks for the result promise
modalInstance.result.then(
function (result) {

// Call the close callback
onClose(result, widget, scope);

// CHECK IF FIRST TIME CONFIGURING THE GADGET - 04/22/2015 BM:
if (!widget.gadgetConfigured) {
    widget.gadgetConfigured = true;                            
    widget.setHeight(widget.fixedSize.height); 
    widget.setWidth(widget.fixedSize.width);                            
}                        
scope.$broadcast('widgetSettingsClosed', widget, result);                                              

//AW Persist title change from options editor         
scope.$emit('widgetChanged', widget);

// hack to recompile the widget if user has swapped gadget types in gadget config modal - 10/01/2015 BM:
if (widget.chartType == "heatmap" || widget.chartType == "treelist") {
    try {
 angular.element(document.getElementById('dash')).scope().$$childHead.compileTemplate();
    } catch (e) {
 console.log("In modalInstance.result.then, cannot compile template " + e);
    }
}
},
function (reason) {
// Call the dismiss callback
onDismiss(reason, scope);
}
);
```

If there's anyone with experience in Mahlar Dashboard, or in compiling directives, I would appreciate any guidance in this area.

thank you,

Bob

Comment: Simply remove old widget and add new widget idea doesn't work?

Comment: let me check the APIs for the remove/add methods. Perhaps I'm over-thinking this, and it's just as simple as that. However I am coming out of the widget's modal settings, so I don't know if I can remove/add at the $modal resolve...I'll experiment now...thanks.

Comment: another way is to make your template dynamic, like <div ng-include="pageName"></div> - so you do not change temaplte , but just change scope variable and template should change itself... not sure if it will work with this library thow

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - honestly I don't think will work. The reason is that I can indeed see the `templateUrl` path getting updated in my `'GadgetSettingsCtrl_NEW'` controller, however if the new html template is NOT recompiled then it doesn't render properly (i.e. I need to refresh my page, then Malhar will re-initialize all widgets).